# How to retrieve value on from in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve value on php page but it's not retrieving value.

Here is my code

**retrieve**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include('conn.php');
$per_page = 3; 
if($_GET)
{
$page=$_GET['page'];
}
$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
$select_table = "select * from clientreg order by id limit $start,$per_page";
$variable = mysql_query($select_table);
?>
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<div style="width:100%;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="tblListForm">
<tr class="listheader">
<td></td>
<td width="230" >*****</td>
</tr>
        <?php
        $i=1;
        $j=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($variable))
        {
        if($j%2==0)
$classname="evenRow";
else
$classname="oddRow";?>
         <tr class="<?php echo $classname;?>">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" ></td>
</tr>
        <?php
        $j++;}
        ?>
            <tr class="listheader">
<td colspan="9"><input type="button" name="update" id="onclick" value="Update" /> <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"  onClick="setDeleteAction();" />
<input type="button" name="assign" id="assign" value="Assign" onClick="setLeadAssignAction();" />

<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM login where  role=1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

?>
<tr class="listheader">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="eid[]" value="<?php echo $row["eid"]; ?>" ><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
</tr>


<?php
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>

<form class="form" method ="Post"action="" id="contact">
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]!="") {
$rowCount = count($_POST["users"]);
for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientreg WHERE Id='" . $_POST["users"][$i] . "'");
$row[$i]= mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "shakti";
  echo $row[$i]['id'];
  }
   }
?>

               <img src="button_cancel.png" class="img" id="cancel"/>   

             <div id="left" style="height:400px;width:47%;float:left;margin-left:20px;margin-top:15px;border-radius:10px;">

                <label>Lead Owner: <span>*</span></label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="leadowner[]" id="lead" placeholder="Lead Owner"value=""/><br/>
                <br/>
                <label>First Name: <span>*</span></label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="fname"id="fname" placeholder="Fname"/><br/>
                <br/>
                <label>Last Name: <span>*</span></label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Lname"/><br/>
                <br/>
                <label>Mobile No: <span>*</span></label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="mobile"id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile"/><br/>
                <br/>
                <label>Email Id: <span>*</span></label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text"name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/><br/>
                </div>
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Where am I wrong in this code?

Please sort out my problem

My problem is here

```
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]!="") {
    $rowCount = count($_POST["users"]);
```

Any help will be appreciated

I have updated my code and added submit button.

Comment: You don't have any submit button, isset will be always false.

Comment: @Fabio i added submit button  stil not working

Comment: Submit button should have a name too.

Comment: @u_mulder i have updated name also

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` see what keys are there.

Comment: @u_mulder: Not necessarily if you don't want to fetch its value inside the PHP script. And in most cases, you don't need the value of the submit button.

Comment: @sheetalsharma: If you're a beginner, please take a tour of the PHP tutorial on W3Schools. It's very comprehensive: http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp.

Comment: what is `if($_GET)` for?

Answer (score 0):

You have two forms. Only the second form has a submit.

Form 1:

```
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?> ">
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
<form class="form" method ="Post"action="" id="contact">
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The if construct does not receive the $_POST["users"], because it receives only the POST of the second submitted form.

```
$rowCount = count($_POST["users"]);
```

$rowCount will always be 0.

Form 2:

```
...
<?php
$rowCount = 0;
if ($_POST["users"] != "") {
     $rowCount = count($_POST["users"]);
} else if ($_POST["rowcount"] != "") {
     $rowCount = $_POST["rowcount"];
}
?>
...
<form class="form" method ="Post"action="" id="contact">
...
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="hidden"  name="rowcount" value="<?php echo $rowCount; ?>">
</form>
```

Then the variable $rowCount will contain the count of the rows after the submit of any of the 2 forms.

Comment: You must probably build one big form out of the 2 separate forms.

Comment: Then you must store the selected user of the first form into a PHP session or into a database table. You will read the stored value for the user, when you deal with the second form.

Comment: could u please a give a small example

Comment: Ok. I was wrong about the PHP session. The PHP session finishes at the end of the PHP script.
So you must use a cookie.
See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp
---------------------

Alternatively you can also modify the second form.
Add this line:
<?php $rowCount = count($_POST["users"]); ?>
to the first form.

<input type="hidden" name="rowcount" value="<?php echo $rowCount; ?> ">
to the second form.
Then you read $_POST["rowCount"] in the second form to get the count of rows.

Comment: still i m getting zero

Comment: Make the full PHP/HTML code available which you have now.

Comment: could you please you email id

Comment: Use this page
http://workupload.com/

Here you can upload your file for free and post the link here.

Comment: what bug ids here could u please short out

Comment: Here e.g. is a bug.


`<tr class="listheader">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="eid[]" value="<?php echo $row["eid"]; ?>" ><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
</tr>`
The checkbox name must noch have the [] brackets:

`<form action="input_checkbox.htm">
  <p>input:</p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="zutat" value="salami">Salami<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="zutat" value="pilze">Pilze<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="zutat" value="sardellen">Sardellen
  </p>
</form>`
$_POST['eid'] fails.

`<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row[$i]['id']; ?>">`
Wrong name.